# How to make a report of how much each of my containers has been used?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a blob storage with multiple containers and I want to create a report based on how much each of these containers has been used (anything like used bandwith or etc.).

If I go to metrics, I find the ingress and Egress which I think can be used for my report, but in the filtering or splittng, there is no way to group by container.

[image]

Comment: Was the below answer helpful for you ? 

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have as of now the ability to break down the metrics based on specific containers, but rather we provide the aggregate of what's in a storage account. More regarding what's supported in terms of Metrics can be found in the following [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-metrics-in-azure-monitor)